# Why does vkd3d not work in wine?

Tags: fedora, nvidia, wine, games, vulkan

I am fairly new to this world, but finally decided to switch from windows and learn the command line in Linux. I also want to play games on it, because my PC isn't the strongest.

I installed Lutris and Epic Games Launcher on my fedora 37 pc. Then I installed Death Stranding, but when I opened it I got this error message from wine:

> CallStack : 2642518428
>
> Your graphics card NVIDIA GeForce  GTX 1060 does not support DirectX12
> features

[image: 1]

It ran on windows though, so I tried turning off DXVK in the runner options in Lutris Epic Games Lanucher configuration.

Then I installed the NVIDIA driver for linux from https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx because I thought maybe the driver is the problem.

I read a lot about this on the internet, but I didn't find anything that worked. Can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should remember Wine isn't Windows. While some applications may work, others may not - for example Epic Launcher seems to, but not all games do. It's a good idea to check [WineHQ application list](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true) first. According to [GamingOnLinux](https://www.gamingonlinux.com/2020/07/directx-12-exclusive-death-stranding-runs-on-linux-with-proton-50-10/page=2/) Death Stranding does work with [Steam Play Proton](https://www.protondb.com/).